# Infinite loop difficulty in C

Tags: c

I have been trying to make a word search game and in this part of the code I have been trying to output 4 random words at random locations such that the words NEVER overlap. However this has been resulting in an infinite loop and i can't understand why. Could you please help me?

This is the code:

```
char getRandomCharacter();
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){

    int randomNum;
    int rand2;
    int rand3;
    char* wordSearch[10][10];
    const char *takenWords[4];
    const char *words[20]={"DOG", "CAT", "ELEPHANT", "CROCODILE", "HIPPOPOTAMUS", "TORTOISE", "TIGER", "FISH", "SEAGULL", "SEAL", "MONKEY", "KANGAROO", "ZEBRA", "GIRAFFE", "RABBIT", "HORSE", "PENGUIN", "BEAR", "SQUIRREL", "HAMSTER"};

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<10; j++){
            wordSearch[i][j]="1";
        }
    }


    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("\n\tA\t\tB\t\tC\t\tD\t\tE\t\tF\t\tG\t\tH\t\tI\t\tJ\n");

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        printf("\n%d\t", i);

            while(i<4){
                do{

                rand2=(rand()%10);
                rand3=(rand()%10);
                if(strcmp(wordSearch[rand2][rand3],"1")==0){
                    int flag=0;
                    do{
                        randomNum = (rand()%20);
                        takenWords[i]=words[randomNum];
                        flag=0;
                        for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
                            if(strcmp(words[randomNum],takenWords[j])==0)flag=1;
                        }
                    }while(flag);
                    printf("%s\n", words[randomNum]);
                }

                }while(strcmp(wordSearch[rand2][rand3],"1")==0);
        printf("\n\n");
            }
    }

        getchar();
        return 0;
}
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: The random characters for the word search are to  be added later..For now I'm just trying to test out the part of getting 4 random words at random positions without them overlapping in any way

Comment: Note: do not use `rand()%10`, `rand()` is not random, instead use `arc4random_uniform(10)` which does return random numbers and does not need seeding..

Comment: @zaph I can't do that :( because our teacher told us to use rand()%10

Comment: @zaph: C does not support methods. OP can use functions, however.

Comment: @zaph: I would not care OP using `rand` here. At least it is portable and there is very likely no need for true random or a uniform distribution in this homework. Sometimes a repeatable sequence is even preferable, e.g. for unit-testing or debugging.

Comment: It is not "a repeatable sequence" because of: `srand(time(NULL));`. The problem I see is that the student will remember using `rand(` and use it in production work. I disagree with teaching flawed methods. `arc4random()` is even easier to use since it does not require seeding.

Comment: @zaph I would certainly use `rand()` *without* seeding until the code is working, so as to debug the same situation every time. Having got that far, then address the issue of randomness.

Comment: Nesting three `while` loops and a `for` loop inside a `for` loop makes understanding the code very difficult. Work on reducing the complexity, refactor portions of the code into functions based on performing a single action. The best suggestion is to re-think the algorithm, it is currently overly complicated. Uniform indentation also helps understanding. Xcode can help with that, just select the code and control-i.

Answer (score 1):

You don't `i++` inside the `while` loop so the execution will never end (as the statement `i<4` will be *always* evaluated to `true`.

Comment: What did you try?
You said your execution never end, I gave you the reason why it doesn't end...

Comment: While this is indeed true the code never gets that far, it is such in the loop inside that one.

Comment: While this is indeed true the code never gets that far, it is stuck in the loop inside that one. See the answer by @Weather Vane.

Comment: @Idos I wrote i++ at the end of the while loop

Comment: I explained my opinion about why it's an endless loop. I didn't say at any point that adding i++ at the end of the while will fix it. I would rewrite the whole thing since it's virtually impossible to understand (many nested whiles/for)...

Comment: dont worry @Idos, I understood what you meant now :)

Comment: No problem. Please consider accepting an answer if it helped you or resolved your problem.

Comment: yes i shall whenever I manage to solve it! :P Thanks for your help though! It's very much appreciated :) @idos

Answer (score 1):

Besides checking the `i` within the `for` loop as pointed out by others, this comparison (and the one in `while()` further down)

```
if(strcmp(wordSearch[rand2][rand3],"1")==0)
```

will always evaluate true because having intialised the grid array with 1-char strings `"1"` they are never changed. That's another reason for infinite loop.

Perhaps that is just as well because the grid strings have room for only one char, and they are pointers to *string literal* anyway, which you cannot overwrite. You can, however, overwrite the *pointer* such as with

```
 wordSearch[rand2][rand3] = words[randomNum];
```

Answer (score 0):

`while(i<4){`

You enter here on the first iteration on the `for` loop; then, since you never change the value of `i` inside the `while` loop, you will get stuck there forever.

Comment: While this is indeed true the code never gets that far, it is stuck in the loop inside that one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pseudo example of simpler code.

The idea is to find the word indexes and then add the word points to the results. No string compares are needed. This does assume that the list of words does not have duplicate entries, if there are then de-dup first.

```
Create a double character pointer array for the results
Create a integer array for taken word indexes
Loop for the number or results (10 in this case)
    set the taken word indexes to -1
    Loop for the numbers of words per set (4 in this case)
        Do
            Create a random word index (in this case 0-19)
            Check if the random word index is already in the taken word indexes
        Exit the loop when an unused index is found
    Add the new word index to the taken word array
    Add the new word pointer to the results
```

That can be written in 12 lines of code.

The code inside the outer loop should really be in a separate function that is called by the outer loop.

Create a function for to check if the random word index is already in the taken word indexes. That function can be written in 10 lines of code including the declaration and return.

Comment: char* wordSearch[10][10];